# Android studio padding or margin around match parent imageview on phone

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a simple ImageView that has layout_width="match_parent". It looks fine there is no margin or padding around the ImageView in the Android Studio, but when I run and test it with my phone an unwanted margin or padding appears around the ImageView. I searched for similar threads but didn't help. I also tried scale types, background color, and negative paddings. These didn't work either.

This problem also appears on all the layout types.

[XML codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhTbL.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/hthtt" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[Margin or padding around the ImageView appears on the tested phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSioS.jpg)

Comment: Welcome. Please read [How do I ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Please post your code as text, not image, so that it can be reproduced by others.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the background color(or other changes) in your drawable (@drawable/hthtt)....share drawable code

Comment: it is a PNG file

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/hthtt"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: it didn't help I still have the same problem, when you do it this way and test it on your phone, does it look fine? no spaces around ImageView?

Comment: yes it works fine, try with layout_width and layout_height different combinations with  adjustViewbounds= "true" use original png dont scale it before using in imageview